# mongodb/mongodb 1.6.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, ubuntu

I am newbie to php , I am trying to run laravel project with mongodb , but i am unable to install mongodb 1.60 php driver

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.6.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed.
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb 1.6.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.6.0].

I tried this command

`sudo apt-get install php-mongodb`

this commands installs mongodb php-mongodb_1.3.4-1build1 .

when i tried to install 1.6 , response says 1.6 version not found

`sudo apt-get install php-mongodb` 
`E: Version '1.6' for 'php-mongodb' was not found`

can anyone please help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the mongodb/mongodb package is a php package, when you're doing the laravel install via composer, it's throwing an error stating it needs the 1.6.0 version of that package.

The problem is it requires your server php to have the ext-mongodb ^1.7 extension.

It currently has the 1.3.4 version.

You can see how to install it here: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php

Comment: thanks for reply @ahackney , I tried to install `composer require mongodb/mongodb^1.7` using this commmand as docs says, but it gives me this error [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                               
  Could not find a matching version of package mongodb/mongodb^1.7. Check the package spelling, your ve  rsion constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability   
  (dev).

Comment: can you please guide me

Comment: You need to follow the link. You're trying to install an extension with composer, this is a server issue. You need to install in your webserver os.

Comment: thanks again @ahackney , i tried in os with this command `sudo apt-get install php-mongodb` this install the 1.3.4-1build1 version , when i forced it to install 1.7 with this `sudo apt-get install php-mongodb=1.7.0` it says `E: Version '1.7.0' for 'php-mongodb' was not found` , thanks in advance

Comment: issue resolved , it was due to php7.2 version  , I upgraded to 7.3 and it resolved , thanks @ahackney

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a mismatch of packages being installed

You could consider removing the packages and installing them as detailed on this page
[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/][1]

See below for ubuntu 18.04
Remove old mongodb packages

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb*
```

Add the correct repo

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the new package

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock                                             
sudo rm -f /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock                                           
sudo rm -f /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid                                          
touch /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid                                               
sudo chown -R  mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/                                
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid                          
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Install the correct driver for mongo (note the php-version 7.2)

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mongodb
```